# Mapping Two Tables value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i had a following table which is displayed below

```
Code    Budhol           COCODE      BEN    FieldNameNew
1      MEDICAL CENTRE   SA          CITY1    PFEmployee
5      MEDICAL CENTRE   SA          CITY1    PF
21     UKTI             UKTI        CITY1    PFEmployee
22     UKTI             UKTI        CITY2    PFEmployee
25     UKTI             UKTI        CITY1    PF
29     UKTI             UKTI        CITY2    PFEmployee
33     UKTI             UKTI        CITY1    PFEmployee
```

Other Table where Mapping is Stored is displayed below

```
FieldName   ComboValue        Code
COCODE       SA                36
COCODE       UKTI              65
BUDHOL       MEDICAL CENTRE    652531
BUDHOL       UKTI              14102
BEN          CITY1             14251
BEN          CITY2             12584
PFEmployee   PFEmployee        7785
PF           PF                7789
```

For **FieldNameNew** there will be only one mapping available in Db

Here is the Final Output which is required

```
Code    Budhol           COCODE      BEN    FieldNameNew
1      652531             36        14251    7785
5      652531             36        14251    7789
21     14102              65        14251    7785
22     14102              65        12584    7785
25     14102              65        14251    7789
29     14102              65        12584    7785
33     14102              65        14251    7785
```

I had tried with Case but it is not optimized i had to hard code data but it is dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
SELECT A.code
    ,Bud.Code AS Budho1
    ,Co.Code AS COCODE
    ,Ben.Code AS BEN
    ,F.Code AS FieldNameNew
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB Bud ON A.Budho1 = Bud.ComboValue
    AND Bud.FieldName = 'BUDHOL'
INNER JOIN TableB Co ON A.COCODE = Co.ComboValue
    AND Co.FieldName = 'COCODE'
INNER JOIN TableB Ben ON A.BEN = Ben.ComboValue
    AND Ben.FieldName = 'BEN'
INNER JOIN TableB F ON A.FieldNameNew = F.ComboValue
```